# Main muestra código viejo en git

Tags: git

en la consola usando git se me fue: git viejo-branch origin y ahora main muestra ese código. Intenté haciendo git pull en main pero nada. También intenté borrando el repo local.

Ahora tengo solo dos branch, pero main sigue mostrando código viejo. No he hecho push por suerte. Esto ocurrió ayer, ¿Puedo devolverme hasta antes de la instrucción que ocasionó la situación?, ¿o puedo hacer que main local apunte al main remoto y tenga la versión correcta del código?

[image: imagen [![git imagen][1]][1]]

Comment: Si tenías un main, creaste una rama y ahora estás trabajando en esa última, es lógico que si cambias a main esté desactualizado. Sólo tienes que volver a la otra rama para seguir trabajando. Si lo que quieres es tener lo último en main, solo tienes que hacer un merge

Comment: Probablemente no has hecho `git pull` sobre tu rama `main` local para que se traiga los cambios que estén en su _upstream_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como comentan si lo que deseas es tener los últimos cambios en main, simplemente debes realizar un "merge":

Realiza un checkout de main:

```
git checkout main
```

Realiza el "merge" con tu branch:

```
git merge viejo-branch
```